# Splitting an Alphabetical List Into Equal Chunks

Tags: c, arrays

I've been tasked with splitting a directory of names into four (approximately) equal chunks. The directory is effectively a phonebook that is already alphebatised. The solution has to be generic and work for any directory not just one specific one. If it helps the directory is an array of strings.

For example the four chunks for one directory could be:

```
A-E, F-L, M-S and T-Z
```

Whilst another could be

```
A-B, C-D, E-F and G-Z
```

I've already considered just splitting the size of the directory in 4 and then counting upwards until reaching that number and noting the letter that entry starts with but that isn't particularly elegant.

What I mean by this is: take the directory to be 100 entries. I could divide this by 4 to get 25 (how many entries should be in each chunk). Going through the entries to 25 and then taking that entry should give me the last entry in the first chunk. However, this doesn't work when the number of entries for each letter in the alphabet vary greatly. A-J could all have one entry and K could have 32 entries which would make my process useless.

It would be helpful to have pseudocode instead of a specific C implementation but really a point in the right direction would be a great help.

Comment: This is not a C-related problem but rather you are asking for us to give you an algorithm?

Comment: @Eregrith I will be doing this in C but I mentioned the pseudocode because I thought it would be more useful for me to actually know what was going on rather than just copy and hack someone else's implementation.

Answer (score 1):

This is an optimization problem in three variables; the boundaries between the four chunks. If we denote the boundaries *x*, *y*, *z* with the chunks half-open intervals `A`-*x*, *x-y*, *y-z*, *z*-`Z` then the only further constraint is that *x <= y <= z*, giving 3276 possibilities for *x, y, z* which is **trivial to search exhaustively**.

Then all you need is a way to score one configuration as better or worse than another; I'd suggest using sum of squared error e.g. for chunk lengths `20, 26, 32, 24` the squared error would be `(20-25)^2 + (26-25)^2 + (32-25)^2 + (24-25)^2 = 76`.

Putting this together, you can write the exhaustive search with nested loops:

```
best, best_error = Nothing, +Inf
for A <= x <= Z:
    for x <= y <= Z:
        for y <= z <= Z:
            error = (sum(lengths[i] for A < i <= x) - 25)^2
                  + (sum(lengths[i] for x < i <= y) - 25)^2
                  + (sum(lengths[i] for y < i <= z) - 25)^2
                  + (sum(lengths[i] for z < i <= Z) - 25)^2
            if error < best_error:
                 best, best_error = (x, y, z), error
```

Comment: I understand mostly what you're suggesting and it looks like it could be a good way to go. However, I'm somewhat confused by the for loops in your implementation. If you could explain them in a bit more detail I would be very grateful.

Comment: @mforrest well, this is an exhaustive search, so *x* can range anywhere from `A` to `Z`. Given that, *y* can be anywhere from *x* to `Z`, and *z* anywhere from *y* to `Z`; nested for loops are the natural representation for that.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I come from a Java background and I'm struggling to implement your solution as is. Is this pseudocode or a working implementation? The `for A <= x <= Z` and `sum(lengths[i] for A < i <= x` are what are confusing me most. Sorry for being a pain but I'm starting to think this is way over my head lol

Comment: @mforrest this is definitely pseudocode. `for A <= x <= Z` would translate as `for (char x = 'A'; x <= 'Z'; ++x)` and `lengths[i]` would be the number of entries with initial letter *i* - this could be a helper function or a lookup table (prepopulated array).

Comment: I'm half following but unfortunately not enough right now to actually implement my own solution. Any chance you could elaborate on your pseudocode?

Answer (score 0):

The directory is already sorted. so you can easily split them into four if you consider extra alphabets as keys like (A-Ae, Af-Az etc.) The basic idea is

1. Store your dictionary in some data structure (say array) in the sorted order
2. Now divide the length of the array by four and make four indices respectively.
3. At each index check the letters with the previous index word.

   - like if 1st index word is "Abandon" and second index word is "Ascension"
     then first key would be "Ab" and second would be "As".
   - So all the words within the range (Ab-As) will be present between the keys.
   - If first two letters are the same like u expect the dictionary to be partially distributed, then go for an additional letter for the key. (like Aba - Abs)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible for the end user by sticking to single character ranges but if I can't get that to work I'll have a look at using your method for sure :)